# How to copy sql files from Github repo to s3 bucket using codepipeline

Tags: github, amazon-s3

I have requirement where i need to copy the files from github repository and move them to the s3 bucket with the codepipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the two stage pipeline where you can put first stage as the github source and second stage as the S3 deploy action also there is check box which you can check to extract the file in S3 bucket. Along with that you can also use the prefix to decide on location.

If we use prefix /test then location of file will be S3 bucket --> / --> test (folder at one level down under /)
If we use prefix test then location of file will be S3 bucket --> test (folder directly)